# How to take last event from cassandra event stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am reading a cassandra event stream and want to get the last element. I am currently doing it like this:

```
def myData: Future[Long] =
  readJournal(myPersistenceId)
    .drop(5)
    .take(1)
    .map(l => l.mydata)
    .runWith(Sink.head)
```

This works because I know that I will be getting `6` events and to get the last one I drop `5` and take `1`. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this such that I am not hardcoding `drop(5)` and `take(1)`. Is there a way to do this such that I always take the last event?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Sink.last`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Sink/last.html#sink-last) or [`Sink.lastOption`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Sink/lastOption.html#sink-lastoption):

```
def myData: Future[Long] =
  readJournal(myPersistenceId)
    .map(_.mydata)
    .runWith(Sink.last)
```

or

```
def myData: Future[Option[Long]] =
  readJournal(myPersistenceId)
    .map(_.mydata)
    .runWith(Sink.lastOption)
```